# optimize TIMESTAMPDIFF in mysql query

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

I need help optimizing a query for large data table
when I test manually it shows fast , but in my slow query log it is logged as taken 10s+ for some reason .

```
SELECT  q.id, q.village_id, q.to_player_id, q.to_village_id,
        q.proc_type, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(),q.end_date) remainingTimeInSeconds
    FROM table
```

I expect to output the results that's time is ended , meaning time left must be 0 or less , in ASC order .

it order by the end time itself ,because when we have many attacks we must arrange them according to which attack suppose to arrive first ,then process them one by one

Comment: I've removed the PHP and PDO tags because there's no PHP code referred to in the question. If you think PHP is relevant to the question, please include the relevant code.

Comment: In the select clause, the `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(),q.end_date)` which calculates the remaining seconds is straightforward and easy to understand. However, the search condition `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(),(q.end_date - INTERVAL (q.execution_time*(q.threads-1)) SECOND)) <= 0` is quite confusing without elaboration for those of us who are not sport enthusiasts. And when you say *I expect to output the results that's time is ended , meaning time left must be 0 or less* , couldn't it be done in a simpler manner than the one in the WHERE clause ?

Comment: And if you can calculate the ramaining seconds using the simple `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(),q.end_date)` , why can't you use `q.end_date <= now()` as your search condition. Without clarification, it's all guess work. Please elaborate.

Comment: thanks for reply , I have edited the post with explain

Comment: *it will get every attack that it supposed to arrive now to the village , which clarify the condition TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(),q.end_date) <= 0* , then why not use `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(),q.end_date) <= 0` or simply `q.end_date <= now()` in the WHERE clause instead  ?

Comment: because it also depends on thread numbers for other purpose which is troops training , the execution time will be depending on how many are under training as you can see in q.end_date - INTERVAL (q.execution_time*(q.threads-1)

Comment: Then I would suggest further clarification on the logic and see if we can rewrite ( and hopefully optimize ) the search condition, as the current one `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(),(q.end_date - INTERVAL (q.execution_time*(q.threads-1)) SECOND)) <= 0` is beyond the capabilities of indexing.

Comment: the game processor is divided into 2 parts , first one will be an. attack which will have only 1 thread , second one is troops training which will have many threads. (each army is a thread ) so we need to calculate (q.end_date - INTERVAL (q.execution_time*(q.threads-1)) so we update it later in order to make training complete by the time is meant to be .

Comment: `<calculation involving one or more columns> <= 0` has to be executed for every single row and can't be shortcut with an index. That means the whole table is loaded in to memory every single time. Where as `<column> <= <calculation>` could use a range seekp to eliminate the irrelevant rows. In your case the calculation will always use a column from the table, and so will always scan the whole table. You should create a calculated column with the timestamp that the row 'expires' (`q.end_date - INTERVAL (q.execution_time*(q.threads-1))`), index it, then use `WHERE x <= NOW()`

Comment: In early 2038, if the software is still used, You will have a DEAD program. timestamp of any flavor has a limited life of functionality - that ends in 2038.  Do not want you to be surprised in your prime of life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the search criteria sargable.

That is, do a calculation on `end_date, execution_time, threads`, store the result in the table and index it.

Then the optimiser can quickly determine which rows are relevant, without scanning the whole table every time.

The following automatically generates and `expiry` column and keeps it up to date if the row is modified.

Then that column is indexed and used in a much simpler WHERE clause.

```
ALTER TABLE
  p_queue
ADD COLUMN
  expiry TIMESTAMP GENERATED ALWAYS
    AS (end_date - INTERVAL (execution time * (threads-1)))
  STORED
;

ALTER TABLE
  p_queue
ADD INDEX
  (expiry)
;

SELECT
  q.id, q.player_id, q.village_id, q.to_player_id, q.to_village_id,
  q.proc_type, q.building_id, q.proc_params, q.threads,
  q.execution_time, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(),q.end_date) remainingTimeInSeconds
FROM
  p_queue q
WHERE
  q.expiry <= NOW()
ORDER BY
  q.expiry ASC
```

Comment: If there is no way to optimize the original search condition to be sargable, then I suppose a generated column with index is the best approach. Thank you.

Comment: @blabla_bingo Is there a known maximum execution time and number of threads? If so, you can do `WHERE <your calculation> AND end_date <= NOW() + INTERVAL (<MAX_EXECUTION_TIME> * (<MAX_THREADS> - 1))`. The latter half could use an index on end date to reduce the search space, and be sargable (using an index on end date). Depending on your data and the max values, that may eliminate enough rows to make the non-sargable search "less painful".

Comment: thank you MatBailie , I will test you and tell you

Comment: thank you very much , it works and it is a lot faster .. but with one big issue , order is different that original query it shows as date time , where the original output results in seconds ( I think it called UNIX_TIMESTAMP)

Answer (score 0):

`TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(),q.end_date) <= 0` can be optimized by changing to to `q.end_date >= NOW()`, but the longer expression cannot be optimized.

See [*sargable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) (See @MatBailie's comment.)

The table would need `INDEX(end_date)`.

For the more complex test, this *might* help:  `INDEX(end_date, execution_time, threads))`